# One x-axis tick every 7 points

Tags: charts, google-visualization

In [area charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart), I'd like to have a tick + label on x-axis **every 7 points** only, instead of one x-axis-tick per point. How to do that in the following code?

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2013',  1000,      400],
      ['2014',  1170,      460],
      ['2015',  660,       1120],
      ['2016',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: you can control the x-axis labels via the option for `hAxis.ticks`, which simply takes an array -- however, this option is only valid for a _continuous_ axis -- which is created using __number__ or __date__ values in the first column of the data table -- __string__ values, as in the example, create a _discrete_ axis, which limits other options as well  -- [discrete-vs-continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous)

Comment: thanks @WhiteHat, could you post a code example?

Comment: In fact I have 1 point per day, and I want one x-axis label every 7 days : Jan 1, Jan 8, Jan 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `hAxis.ticks` option to provide custom *x-axis* labels

the option takes an array `[]` of values,
of the same type used for the axis (first column in the data table)
in this case `'date'`

see following working snippet...

- a point is added for each day since `'12/07/2016'`
- a tick is added every 7th day

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MMM d'
  });

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Day');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Y');
  dataTable.addColumn({role: 'style', type: 'string'});

  var oneDay = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  var startDate = new Date(2016, 11, 7);
  var endDate = new Date();
  var ticksAxisH = [];
  for (var i = startDate.getTime(); i < endDate.getTime(); i = i + oneDay) {
    // set row date
    var rowDate = new Date(i);
    var xValue = {
      v: rowDate,
      f: formatDate.formatValue(rowDate)
    };

    // y = 2x - 8
    var yValue = (2 * ((i - startDate.getTime()) / oneDay) - 8);

    dataTable.addRow([
      xValue,
      yValue,
      'point {fill-color: #003eff;}, line {stroke-color: #003eff;}'
    ]);

    // add tick every 7 days
    if (((i - startDate.getTime()) % 7) === 0) {
      ticksAxisH.push(xValue);
    }
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);
  chart.draw(dataTable, {
    colors: ['#e6f4f9'],
    areaOpacity: 1.0,
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        color: '#f5f5f5'
      },
      ticks: ticksAxisH
    },
    legend: 'none',
    pointSize: 4,
    vAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        color: '#f5f5f5'
      }
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Last thing: how to make the grid lines smaller (1px only) and lighter, and have a round dot for each point [like in Google Analytics](http://gget.it/7msmlbvq/1.jpg)? Last last thing: could we remove the right `--- Y` legend. PS: it's for a MIT open-source project that will be available soon on. I'll start a bounty to offer points to thank you!

Comment: Thanks again @WhiteHat. Last thing: I didn't find in the doc how to change the "area color" to #e6f4f9, would you have an idea? PS: can I cite you as contributor in README.md?

Comment: I'd like to keep original darker blue for line + dots, and this light blue only for area under curve, any idea @WhiteHat? (How can I cite you, do you have a github username? [mine is here](http://github.com/josephernest)).

Comment: changed answer again -- having a different color for the area from the line + points requires adding a `'style'` column to the data table -- see value for new column, which takes care of line + points -- the original `colors` option supplies the area color -- by default the chart limits the `areaOpacity`, which is why the light blue was so much lighter earlier -- added option for `areaOpacity: 1.0`